# Show html tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the code in html and ts file. Content in variable **Description** is `<div>aaaa</div><div>bbbb</div><div>cccc</div>`

Now the result show

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

How to make it show in 3 line

```
aaaa 
bbbb 
cccc
```

OR show with space

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
```

html file code

```
<span>
 {{getHtml(Description)}}
</span>
```

ts file code

```
getHtml(html) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div.innerHTML
}
```

Comment: whats the rendered source look like? maybe you have `display: inline-block` somewhere, also don't wrap div's with a span, also it should be noted, your want to refactor tags out into a tags array separate from the description, else you're just opening yourself up to XSS if your allowing arbitrary HTML/JS to be added to things

Comment: Check that the information is really displayed in divs. A div is a block-level element and always starts in a new line

Comment: You can use `textarea` tag for showing html tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the element pre:

```
<pre>
   {{YOUR_VALUE}}
</pre>
```

Comment: `data` is undefined ;p

Comment: It should be your own value...
like: `Description`

Comment: but wont that escape the html in YOUR_VALUE?

Comment: If your desire is to show RAW HTML - save it as string and render it inside `<pre>` tag